# Get User configuration from database in a global variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I'm newbie in Codeigniter.
I have a table in my database called 'sysConfig' with columns such as title, money unit, license key and ... .

I want to get first line of this table record (it has only one record) to a global variable called '$Config' that it available in all views (If it was possible available in models and controllers).

Edit:
I can select any data from database and I dont have any problem with this. I want to select data on table sysConfig in a variable called $Config and access ti it directly like this `<?php echo $Config['Title']; ?>` or `<?php echo $Config -> Title; ?>`.

Comment: Read the documentations before asking any question. for example you can go through this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: @sayantan-das I can select any data from database and I dont have any problem with this. I want to select data on table sysConfig in a variable called $Config and access ti it directly.

Comment: Then you can add a helper   file and write a function in the helper  like 'getConfig('config_name_here')' which would retrive the requested config value..now if you autoload your custom helper, all the functions in that helper would be available throughout your project. you'd be able to access it like, <?= getConfig('config_name') ?>

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, if these are system config items is to load them in your own config file.

Create your own config file. Load it manually or in autoload.

```
$this->config->load('filename');
```

Access items in it like this

```
$this->config->item('item_name');
```

You can also set dynamicallly the config items using this:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

You can read about it here in the docs: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Alternatively, if this is user based, collect the information into the current session and access that. Although accessing session variables in models or libraries is not a good idea. You should pass the required items as function arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I load this items from database? Because each user has own setting, I cant save them in file.

Comment: Once you have authenticated a user, you can just set them into the session variable, and as long as the session remains that data will be accessible. You can do this just on login for instance, $_SESSION['licence'] = $licence, $_SESSION['something_else'] = $something_else etc. I would suggest you use a DB for storing sessions. Once stored access the session variable $_SESSION['licence'] directly at any time.

Comment: Personally, I would set a library call within the authorization procedure (is this user logged in) that gets the user_id, then checks the table by user_id for licence etc, and returns that data to the controller. The controller then sends whatever info is needed from that (if at all) to the models or libraries as arguments. I would not check those variables in session or anywhere else from within the models themselves. In this way if your system changes you only have to change one thing in one place, not multiple functions in multiple places.

Comment: After user registered, he/she specific some setting for ever, Such as system language, theme, direction, .... this settings can't save in session or cookie because if user signed in from another browser, must set this setting again! I saved this setting in database and just I want to assign them to '$Config' variable that I described in question.

Comment: Then fine, set them dynamically during the authorisation procedure as described in my answer using $this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value'); There are a hundred ways to achieve this and setting config items on the fly is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a property to any controller that will need `sysConfig` data. The name of the variable should not be $config because CI already uses that symbol - it is defined and set by the `Config` class. So for this answer I will use `$sysConfig`.

```
class Some_controller extends CI_Controller
{
  protected $sysConfig; //class property with scope to this controller

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('sysConfig_model');
  }
```

`sysConfig_model` (not shown) manages the table you seem to have established. I'm making up functions for that model since you don't show us any code. The model function `get($id)` retrieves the "user" you want based on `$id` and returns the data in an array. (The setting of `$id` with a valid value is not shown.)

The controller can make use of the property as needed by way of `$this->sysConfig` as in this admittedly trivial made-up controller function.

The class definition continues with...

```
  public function format_title()
  {
     if(isset($this->sysConfig){
       $this->sysConfig['suckup'] = "the most highly regarded " 
       . $this->sysConfig['title'] 
       . " in the world visit our site!";
     }
  }
```

Actually assigning a value to `$this->sysConfig` happens in this next bit of code. In this example, the controller's `index()` function can receive an argument that is the "ID" of the user we want to get from the database.

```
  public function index($id = NULL)
  {
    //assign data to the class property $sysConfig from the model
     $this->sysConfig = $this->sysConfig_model->get($id);
```

The property can be passed to a view quite easily. First we do some sucking up.

```
     $this->format_title(); 
     $data['userStuff'] = $this->sysConfig;
     $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
  } //end of index()

} //end of class Some_controller
```

**some_view.php**

```
<div>
  <h4>Welcome <?php echo $userStuff['firstName']. " " . $userStuff['lastName']; ?></h4>
  <p>I cannot say how swell it is to have <?php echo $userStuff['suckup']; ?></p>
</div>
```

The idea of a "global" is really contrary to OOP methodology in PHP - or any other OOP language.